# I want to put text to a google marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, marker

I want to put text to a google marker, as well as the image, but I can not find the way to do it, since the text would get it from a web service, could they help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to Google maps marker?

Comment: Correct to google map markers, but for android and I want to put the text on the google marker.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about google maps marker. you can use the title in order to add text to the marker.
i.e.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Hello World!"
});

// To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
marker.setMap(map);
```

Check the documentation on [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Another option mention here is to use the labels text :
[How to add text label in Google Map API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338998/how-to-add-text-label-in-google-map-api)

Comment: I did not know how to express the app is for an android app using maps, what I want for an app from gas stations, I want to put image of the oil company, and in the middle the price of fuel or need to click, See in the marking, and I was watching the title of the bookmarks and what appears is just put a title letter but I need to show more characters.