# Add some label with text on google maps API (js)

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

This is my google maps script:

```
   <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: 42.643484, lng: 23.3355926};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 18,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyALIoCDadlZFkBXVHqvvnM6jEaYXllAjbk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I want to add some label text (like picture bellow). I tried almost everythig who found here and in google, but without success.
If someone can help ..

[image]

Comment: Seems duplicated, take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344251/4112296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this, https://jsfiddle.net/linushg111/jr3uoag1/ It's a modified version of this one https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

```
function initMap() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850, -87.650);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: chicago,
    zoom: 3
  });

  var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  coordInfoWindow.setContent(createInfoWindowContent(chicago, map.getZoom()));
  coordInfoWindow.setPosition(chicago);
  coordInfoWindow.open(map);

  map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    coordInfoWindow.setContent(createInfoWindowContent(chicago, map.getZoom()));
    coordInfoWindow.open(map);
  });
}

var TILE_SIZE = 256;

function createInfoWindowContent(latLng, zoom) {
  var scale = 1 << zoom;

  var worldCoordinate = project(latLng);

  var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
      Math.floor(worldCoordinate.x * scale),
      Math.floor(worldCoordinate.y * scale));

  var tileCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
      Math.floor(worldCoordinate.x * scale / TILE_SIZE),
      Math.floor(worldCoordinate.y * scale / TILE_SIZE));

  return [
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum arcu at velit sodales, vitae tempor dui facilisis. Nulla luctus interdum magna, non porta libero imperdiet et. Morbi tincidunt orci quis tellus maximus, ut varius augue feugiat. Donec ullamcorper faucibus quam sit amet mattis. Cras nec dui pretium, vulputate ligula vitae, sodales diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus  '
  ].join('<br>');
}

// The mapping between latitude, longitude and pixels is defined by the web
// mercator projection.
function project(latLng) {
  var siny = Math.sin(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180);

  // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
  // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
  siny = Math.min(Math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);

  return new google.maps.Point(
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.lng() / 360),
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * Math.PI)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using InfoWindows from the Google API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

The InfoWindow will accept a HTML input to return you an object which can be tagged to an onClick event listener to your marker.

```
let info = new gmaps.InfoWindow({
        content: eventInfoContent // this will be the html for your design
    });
gmaps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () =>{
        info.open(map,marker);
});
```

Hope this helps!